# Error Could not install package 'Autodesk.Forge.Design.Automation beta 3.0.0'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, autodesk-designautomation

while trying to add "Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation" nuget package to project following error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error Could not install package 'Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation 3.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.    "       0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've hit the same issue [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1707)...

So try upgrade your NuGet to 3.4.4 [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2015).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a **.Net core / .Net standard** project not a **.NetFramework**. Ref: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation.

Answer (score 0):

.net 4.7.1 supports .net standard 2.0 so you should be able to install this package. In fact, I have no problem installing this package using VS 2019 into a .net 4.7.1 project.

It looks like you use VS 2015 so I suspect that this is limitation of VS 2015. Try to use the latest nuget.exe and manually install the package. Or use the latest Visual Studio.